# ASP.NET Forward userid from AuthorizeAttribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I've got a AuthorizeAttribute class that intercepts calls to my Web Api. There I valdiate users from the session that is given.

If the user has the right credentials, I would like to append the request body with the userId that was fetched during credential checks. I've tried some stuff but it seem that I can't access the request body in IsAuthorized?

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
public class AuthorizeUserAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool IsAuthorized(HttpActionContext httpContext)
    {
        // Pick up session
        var sessionKey = httpContext.Request.Headers.FirstOrDefault(h => h.Key == "session").Value;

        // If session vas valid, get userid from session and add it to the request body somehow
        // so the controller gets userid attached.

        return true;
    }
}
```

After, the target controller gets called:

```
public Response GetCandy( CandyRequest candy )
{
    // Wohoo, the user was accepted and i've got the user id already in the argument object.
    var userId = candy.UserId;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I entirely understand what you're seeking here. If you're trying to get access to `candy` and set the `UserId` from within your attribute, you're probably going to have a rough time. You maybe able to add it to do something with `httpContext.ActionArguements` before model binding happens to inject your user ID.

But, I've always understood AuthorizeAttribute's as something that is a gatekeeper and shouldn't be setting data inside of it. With that being said, one workaround you could use `HttpContext.Items` to set items for the request, so your resulting code would look like

```
protected override bool IsAuthorized(HttpActionContext httpContext)
{
    // code to map the session to the user.

    HttpContext.Current.Items["UserId"] = 23423; // set the user id to the Items collection

    return true;
}
```

then in your controller

```
public Response GetCandy( CandyRequest candy )
{
    // Wohoo, the user was accepted and i've got the user id already in the argument object.
    var userId = HttpContext.Items["UserId"];
}
```